# realurl on a subdomain - 'can't find the files on the server'- error

Tags: php, .htaccess, typo3-6.2.x

**What I am trying to do:**

A working real-url installation which gives out only the last pathsegment of the navigation not `ttt.bbb.org/navi/about/project` but `ttt.bbb.org/project`.

It should work on the subdomain and then be transferable to another server where it is on a main domain. The subdomain is only the sandbox for the upgrade of the project.

**The system:**

Typo3 6.2.14 on a subdomain (`ttt.bbbb.org`) with symlinks to the typo3 `src` and `index.php` in the root-directory on a strato-server.

**The error:**

`realurl` does convert the php-endings into speaking URLs but can't find the files on the server.

**My questions are:**

1. Which folder is the right one for the .htaccess-file? Do i put real
   url into the typo3_src or into the installation of the project?

**`ts-template`:**

```
config.simulateStaticDocuments = 0
config.baseURL = http: //www.ttt.bbb.org/
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1
config.uniqueLinkVars = 1
config.linkVars = L(0-3)
```

**`.htaccess`:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3/.*$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* typo3_ttt/index.php
```

**`realurl.conf`:**

```
<?php
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['addRootLineFields'].= ',tx_realurl_pathsegment';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'init' => array(
            'enableCHashCache' => 1,
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => 1,
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => 1,
            'postVarSet_failureMode' => '',
        ),
        'redirects' => array(),
        'preVars' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        'nc' => 1,
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'L',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        # 'de' => '0',
                        'en' => '1',
                    ),
                    'valueDefault' => 'de',
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
            ),
            'pagePath' => array(
                'type' => 'user',
                'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
                'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                'expireDays' => 7,
                'rootpage_id' => 42,
                'firstHitPathCache' => 1,
            ),
            'fixedPostVars' => array(),
            'postVarSets' => array(
                '_DEFAULT' => array(
                    // news archive parameters
                    'archive' => array(
                        array(
                            'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[year]' ,
                        ),
                        array(
                            'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[month]' ,
                            'valueMap' => array(
                            'january' => '01',
                            'february' => '02',
                            'march' => '03',
                            'april' => '04',
                            'may' => '05',
                            'june' => '06',
                            'july' => '07',
                            'august' => '08',
                            'september' => '09',
                            'october' => '10',
                            'november' => '11',
                            'december' => '12',
                        )
                    ),
                ),
                // news pagebrowser
                'browse' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[pointer]',
                    ),
                ),
                // news categories
                'select_category' => array (
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[cat]',
                    ),
                ),
                // news articles and searchwords
                'article' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[tt_news]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array(
                            'table' => 'tt_news',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'title',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                'strtolower' => 1,
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[backPid]',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[swords]',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        // configure filenames for different pagetypes
        'fileName' => array(
            'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 1,
            'index' => array(
                'print.html' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 98,
                    ),
                ),
                'rss.xml' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 100,
                    ),
                ),
                'rss091.xml' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 101,
                    ),
                ),
                'rdf.xml' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 102,
                    ),
                ),
                'atom.xml' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 103,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you should put .htaccess file in your **www** root (same folder where *index.php* (or symlink) stored)

2) Default folder for real URL config file - typo3conf (actually you can change it in real URL properties with extension manager)

3) In your ts - config.baseURL = http: //www.ttt.bbb.org/ is really "space" after http:// ?

Comment: thank you. I did put .htaccess in the same folder as index php. which in my case is the typo.3/6.14 folder. than i put the conf into the folder which is described in the real-url conf and i took the space out of the url. now i get  a 404-error